# rxjava, how to inspect the result of a Single

Tags: kotlin, rx-java3, rx-java-completable

using kotlin, having code

```
fun fetchRemoteDataApi(): Single<RemoteDataResponse> = networkApi.getData()

    // it is just a retrofit
    @GET(".../api/getData")
    fun getData() : Single<RemoteDataResponse>

fun mergeApiWithDb(): Completable = fetchRemoteDataApi()
            .zipWith(localDao.getAll())
            .flatMapCompletable { (remoteData, localData) ->
                doMerge(remoteData, localData) //<== return a Completable
            }
```

the code flow:

```
    val mergeApiDbCall = mergeApiWithDb().onErrorComplete().cache() //<=== would like do some inspection at this level
    PublishSubject.create<Unit>().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .compose(Transformers.flowableIO())
                .switchMap {
                    //merge DB with api, or local default value first then listen to DB change
                    mergeApiDbCall.andThen(listAllTopics())
                            .concatMapSingle { topics -> remoteTopicUsers.map { topics to it } }
                }
                .flatMapCompletable { (topics, user) ->
                    // do something return Completable
                }
                .subscribe({
                    ...
                }, { throwable ->
                    ...
                })
```

and when making the call

```
val mergeApiDbCall = mergeApiWithDb().onErrorComplete().cache()
```

the question is if would like to inspect on the `Singles<RemoteDataResponse>` returned from `fetchRemoteDataApi()` (i.e. using Log.i(...) to printout the content of `RemoteDataResponse`, etc.), either in got error or success case, how to do it?

```
/// the functions
fun listAllTopics(): Flowable<List<String>> = localRepoDao.getAllTopics()

// which a DAO:
    @Query("SELECT topic FROM RemoteDataTable WHERE read = 1")
    fun getAllTopics(): Flowable<List<String>>

///
private val remoteTopicUsers: Single<List<User>>
        get() {
            return Single.create {
                networkApi.getTopicUsers(object : ICallback.IGetTopicUsersCallback {
                    override fun onSuccess(result: List<User>) = it.onSuccess(result)
                    override fun onError(errorCode: Int, errorMsg: String?) = it.onError(Exception(errorCode, errorMsg))
                })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract information about elements from the `Completable`. Though you can use `doOnComplete()` on `Completable`, it will not provide you any information about the element.

You can inspect elements if you call `doOnSuccess()` on your `Single`, so you need to incorporate this call earlier in your code. To inspect errors you can use `doOnError()` on both `Completable` or `Single`.